# Getting not defined variables, not sure why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running this script to save the item to localstorage but for some reason, I run okay on localhost. But when I deployed to my server, I get error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $data is not defined

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/michaelt05/sgr9bLwy/1/

Here is my js code:

var wish_list = new Array();

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".wishlist").on("click", function() {
    $data = "";
    $product_id = $(this).attr("product_id");
    $product_name = $(this).attr("product_name");
    $prduct_price = $(this).attr("product_price");
    //check if the element is in the array
    if ($.inArray($product_id, wish_list) == -1) {
      $product_str = "<tr class='wishlist-item' id='list_id_" + $product_id + "'><td class='w-pname'>" + $product_name + "</td><td class='w-price'>$ " + $prduct_price + "</td><td class='w-premove' wpid='" + $product_id + "'>x</td></tr>";
      $("#wish_list_item").append($product_str);
      wish_list.push($product_str);
      show_message("Product " + $product_name + " added");
      count_items_in_wishlist_update();

    }

  });

  //adding toggle functionality to the wishlist panel
  $(".wish_list_heading").on("click", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("up")) {
      $("#wish_list").css("height", "300px");
      $(this).addClass("up");
      $("#wish_list").css("overflow", "auto");
    } else {
      $("#wish_list").css("height", "30px");
      $(this).removeClass("up");
      $("#wish_list").css("overflow", "hidden");
    }

  });

  $("#wish_list_item").on("click", ".w-premove", function() {
    $product_id = $(this).attr("wpid");
    $("#list_id_" + $product_id).remove();



    wish_list = $.grep(wish_list, function(n, i) {
      return n != $product_id;
    });
    show_message("Product removed");
    count_items_in_wishlist_update();
  });
});

function show_message($msg) {
  $("#msg").html($msg);
  $top = Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $("#msg").outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px";
  $left = Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $("#msg").outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px";
  $("#msg").css("left", $left);
  $("#msg").animate({
    opacity: 0.6,
    top: $top
  }, 400, function() {
    $(this).css({
      'opacity': 1
    });
  }).show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#msg").animate({
      opacity: 0.6,
      top: "0px"
    }, 400, function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }, 1000);
}

//Validation against the amount of product being added
function count_items_in_wishlist_update() {
  $("#listitem").html(wish_list.length);
  if (wish_list.length > 1) {
    $("#p_label").html("Products");
  } else {
    $("#p_label").html("Product");
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless `$data` is defined somewhere outside of the code you posted, you never formally define it before trying to assign a value to it. You (may) need to use `let`/`const`/`var`.

Comment: `$data = "";` this is the only instance in your code that uses `$data`. Are you sure the error is in this code?

Comment: @Alvi15 `Uncaught ReferenceError: $data is not defined` is the error code I get in my Console

Comment: Better to remove `$data` since set once but never used. Also, it is good practice to always define variables with `const`, `let`, or the older `var`, such as `const $product_id = $(this).attr("product_id");`